# After deployment of win app with SQL Server Express database I got error as "cannot open database login failed"

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I made a win forms app with SQL Server Express with Visual Studio 2010.
When I deploy my app by right click on Solution Explorer selecting Properties and then Publish and following all the procedure.

When I install on other system, error occured. The error was:

> cannot open database [dbname] login requested by user [username] failed...

I googled much but no use. I think it might be in connectionstring, if it is so, what and how should be connectionstring or any other alternative.

Comment: How about you post your actual connectionstring first? hard to help without any extra information

Comment: did you deploy with the config file?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

1st- check if your connection string is correct and make it specific like dont use dot. try to use IP address on your server name(dont forget to include \SQLexpress if needed). also if u are using windows authentication(without user id and password) you need to add on the connection string: "integrated security=SSPI"

2nd- off firewall. firewall blocks all remote connection

3rd- check hardware, ping the server and make sure the client can see the server

Answer (score 0):

If you have Integrated Security = true in your connection string you will have to provide a sql server login and a database user in SQL Server for your users. Alternatively, you can set up a specific SQL Server login and database user for your app, grant it least-privaledged permissions in SQL Server, and then specify it in your connection string as user=myuser;password=mypassword;

Then remove the integrated security = true portion altogether.